# How can i authenticate the user's input?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Building a chatbot using node.js that will be communicating with Luis.

```
 if (!meeting.datetimeV2) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'what is the date and time');
        } else {
            next();
        }
```

This section is supposed to take date and time code for example:

```
Bot: what is the date and time?
human:today at 5pm
```

The issue i'm having is that the bot is accepting inputs like `jagahgdh` or `ffffff` basically troll answers which is expected due to the use of `builder.Prompts.text` but my question is how can i fix that and make sure the users input has the proper format or i'll have to ask the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

using NER (Named Entity Recognition) you can check if the user's input contains a "date" and a "time" entities - if not prompt the same question

Comment: I'm not sure i completely understood that, can you explain more and provide an example.

Comment: Using entities (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/add-entities) you can check if the user's input contains a "date". Luis has a list of pre-built entities (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/pre-builtentities) that you can check here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities